Fantasy movie with evil queen from the 2000's?
I'm looking for an American movie that I watched on TV, it was dubbed in my language. I'm not sure when exactly I watched it but it must have been between 2002 and 2008.
It was a fantasy movie, it took place in medieval times, I guess, because there was a kingdom. I think the king married with a woman who was evil. There was a scene where she just sat on a throne or a bed calmly and her body burned while she was slowly rocking herself sideways making her look like a rotten corpse.
And there was a girl who was the only one who could stop that evil queen. Someone took her to a cave where she learned that she had to stop the queen with her breath of ice, I guess. The evil queen was blonde and the heroine had black hair.

Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors?

it was probably an american movie it was dubbed in my language so :/ i'm not sure when exactly i watched it but it must be between 2002 and 2008 the queen was blonde and the heroine was black haired i don't remember any other details sorry

Could be one of the Fantaghiro movies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantaghirò_series

no it's not the queen is blonde actually i don't even know if she becomes the queen maybe she's just hooking up with the king :s thanks for answering!

It's Kull the Conqueror (1997)
After five years as a slave, warrior Kull travels to the shores of the fantastical kingdom of Valusia, where he slays mad King Borna. Inheriting the crown, Kull begins an ambitious program of bringing freedom and tolerance to Valusia, which displeases Gen. Taligaro and the royal court's advisers. Determined to unseat Kull, Taligaro and the king's cousin conspire to bring Akivasha, Sorceress Queen of Acheron, back to life, to destroy Kull and take the crown themselves.
Akivasha seduces Kull with ease and marries him. Once married, she becomes Queen and promptly poisons Kull, who is believed by the royal court to be dead; however, Kull reawakens to find out the truth about Akivasha. He frees himself from confinement and plots to regain his throne and vanquish the evil witch. He is joined in his quest by Ascalante, a priest of an old abandoned god whom Kull had freed earlier, and Zareta, Ascalante's sister and fortune-teller, who was a member of Kull's harem wrongfully accused of his murder by the queen and who secretly loves Kull.
The only way to destroy Akivasha, however, is to sail to steal the icy breath of Valka, a cave-dwelling northern god. Armed with this knowledge, Kull, Zareta and her priestly brother Ascalante Litefoot sail off on an exciting, dangerous quest that will lead them to tangle with strange creatures and villains.
What results is a series of tests and adventures which ultimately results in the death of the witch, the reinstatement of Kull as King, the abolishment of the slavery of Valusia, the reformation of the laws of the lands, and the inclusion of a new Queen.Wikipedia / IMDB / Rottentomatoes / 











Well done. Great answer. Just wishing that movie didn't exist. I remember thinking of it as a horrible adaptation of Howard's material.

thank you so much yeah i think this is it i remember it a lot fancier tho hahah anyways thanks for your hard work i appreciate it!!
